# Why multipart is not generating close events

Tags: node.js, http, express, coffeescript

Hi I won't to handle upload stream by myself without touching a disk drive.
So, the natural selection for me was multiparty module.

I took the general example and according the instruction from page https://npmjs.org/package/multiparty I changed form.parse to non callback request. In that case the disk won't be touched.

My code looks like this:

```
multiparty = require("multiparty")
http = require("http")
util = require("util")

# show a file upload form
http.createServer((req, res) ->
  if req.url is "/upload" and req.method is "POST"
    form = new multiparty.Form()

    form.on 'error', (err) ->
      console.log "Error received #{err}"

    form.on 'aborted',  ->
      console.log "Aborted"

    form.on 'part', (part) ->
      console.log "Part"

    form.on 'close', (part) ->
      console.log "close received"
      res.writeHead 200,
        "content-type": "text/plain"
      res.end "received upload:\n\n"

    form.on 'progress', (bytesReceived, bytesExpected) ->
      console.log "Received #{bytesReceived}, #{bytesExpected}"

    form.parse req
  else
    res.writeHead 200,
      "content-type": "text/html"

    res.end "<form action=\"/upload\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\">" + "<input type=\"text\" name=\"title\"><br>" + "<input type=\"file\" name=\"upload\" multiple=\"multiple\"><br>" + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload\">" + "</form>"
).listen 8080
```

the console output looks like this:

```
Part
Part
Received 64983, 337353
Received 130519, 337353
Aborted
Error received Error: Request aborted
```

The close event is not generated so I don't know when the end of reading the socket. 
If I change the line:

```
form.parse req
```

to:

```
form.parse req, (err, fields, files) ->
  res.writeHead 200,
    "content-type": "text/plain"

  res.write "received upload:\n\n"
  res.end util.inspect(
    fields: fields
    files: files
  )
```

Then everything is fine and the close event is called. But the file is stored on the disk. The console looks like this:

```
Part
Part
Received 65536, 337353
Received 131072, 337353
Received 196608, 337353
Received 262144, 337353
Received 327680, 337353
Received 337353, 337353
close received
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: no, I rewrite it in a different way, to avoid such problems.

Comment: can you show how you rewrote it so other people can also find a solution? :)

Comment: @DallaRosa I can try to do that next week. This week I'm facing some deadlines, no chance for that, especially I don't remember now how it works :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, since you are not piping the data to a file, `close` is emitted only when all data has been piped out of the `req` object, causing `req` to internally emit it's `finish` event, which triggers the multiparty `close` event.

**In practice, if you need the `close` event, always pull the data out of the part, whether it is to a blackhole or a meaningful location (file or temporary holding stream).** This also means it can be very tricky to use the `close` event for continuing control flow.

If you don't want to do anything with the data you can blackhole it like so:

```
form.on("part", function(part) {
    out = new stream.Writable(); // require("stream") to get this native class
    out._write = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
        done(); // Don't do anything with the data
    };
    part.pipe(out);
});
```

The confusing part is that code which does not access the `part` will call the `close` event for small files, but not be called on large files (how I ran into this issue). The reason for that is that the `close` event isn't bound to whether you have read the data from the `part` but whether all data has been transferred out of the `req`.

Node streams only transmit a few chunks at a time between their buffers. Thus, small files are able to transfer their entire buffer from `req` to `part` without filling `part`'s internal buffer. Larger files will fill the buffer of the `part` but still have data left over in the `req`, requiring a read on the `part` to get the data remaining in the `req` buffer.

This fact also makes it tricky to use the `close` event for anything regarding control flow. In example, a `part` can still be processing, but `close` will be sent, again because `close` isn't dependent on `part` completion, but rather on `req` being empty. Confusing!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need at least to read any received part somewhere in order to complete the request processing, and trigger the close event :

```
form.on('part', function(part) {
    part.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/dev/null'));
});
```

Without this, I guess it is like your request is still waiting to be processed.
(Note that there is more elegant, less scripty way than that "> /dev/null" stuff, but it is just as an example ;)