# close event is not called

Tags: node.js, azure, express, multipart

I am using node-multiparty, trying to save stream image to azure blob storage, but the 'close' event is not called?:

```
var form = new multiparty.Form();
var fields = [];
var parts = [];

form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error parsing form: ' + err.stack);
});

form.on('field', function(name, value){
    fields.push({name:name, value: value});
});

form.on('part', function(part){
    parts.push({name:part.name, value:part});
});

form.on('close', function(){
        // How do I get the name called image from parts array, and save it to the azure storage?
        var filename = part.filename;
        var size = part.byteCount;

        var onError = function(error) {
            if (error) {
                res.send({ grrr: error });
            }
        };
        blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream('container', filename, part,    size, onError);  
});
```

Comment: `part` is a readable stream accessible inside the `part` event. You should put logic for uploading to azure in `part` event. Example https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty/blob/master/examples/azureblobstorage.js

Comment: I want to check some information on the fields, before uploading.

Comment: what kind of information?

Comment: Information from the fields.

Comment: Okay I got it, during the POST I have to put fields on top of files.

Comment: Hi, Alvin, have you solved your issue now?

Answer (score 1):

We can refer to the answer of [Why multipart is not generating close events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598546/why-multipart-is-not-generating-close-events) to get the hint of why you cannot emit the `close` event.

> since you are not piping the data to a file, close is emitted only when all data has been piped out of the req object, causing req to internally emit it's finish event, which triggers the multiparty close event.

So beside to put all the fields on top of files in the form, you can try to leverage `file` event to host the files in tmp folder and handle them in `close` event later. E.G:

```
var blobService = azure.createBlobService();
var form = new multiparty.Form({autoFiles:true});
var fields = [];
var files = [];
form.on('field', function(name, value){
    fields.push({name:name, value: value});
});
form.on('file',function(name,file){
  files.push(file);
});
form.on('close',function(){
  console.log(files);
  var file = files[0];
    var onError = function(error) {
        if (error) {
            res.send({ grrr: error });
        }
    };

    blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(container, file.originalFilename, fs.createReadStream(file.path),file.size,file.headers, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      // error handling
      console.log(error);
    }else{
      res.end('File uploaded successfully');
    }
  });
});
form.parse(req);
```